# Map field from other table JPA (Spring boot)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Entity 1

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Company  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int companyId;
    private String name;


    @Transient
    private int haveFavoriteUser;

}
```

Entity 2

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private String userId;



}
```

Entity 3

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Favorite implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int favoriteId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "companyId")
    private Company company;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT CE.*, IF(F.companyId = CE.companyId, 1, 0) as haveFavoriteUser FROM Company CE " + //
            "LEFT JOIN Favorite F ON CE.companyId = F.companyId " + //
            "WHERE F.userId = :user ORDER BY CE.name", //
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Company> findAllFavorite(@Param("user") String user);
}
```

I want, in my jpa repository map value "haveFavoriteUser", with the load from other entity (favorite). How can I do this?

I don't want merge favorite inside company because only I need one field.

Thank you so much.

Comment: haveFavoriteUser is transient, it will not be saved?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to be saved, because only I want use this field when I am reading the object from API.

Comment: Do not use the same object as entity and as API. Learn about 3-tier architecture

Comment: Bu then, how can I get and object inside object with jpa? Like List<Object> in my company.

Comment: You cant, because it is not persist. Where shpuld it come from if it is not in the database?

Comment: I want to map with the IF in native query, that use other table, which is "Favorite"

Comment: You have to put it in as parameter

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Put it in as parameter like `@Param("user") String user`

Comment: But that is for filter or to pass a param, I don't wanna do that. I want to get in a single query one object (Company) that have a value filled from other table (favorite). That is what I'm doing in the IF.